c# console app: dependent assemblies in alternate directory
I have a small .NET Framework 4.8 (C#) console app that references a DLL from another application, which in turn depends on a large number of DLLs from the other application. If I copy the dependencies to the folder with the .exe, it works fine:
bin/
  my_console_app.exe             --> References "referenced.dll"
  referenced.dll                 --> Depends on a.dll, b.dll, ...
  a.dll
  b.dll
  ...

But to make things easier to manage, I'd like to put the dependencies in their own directory:
bin/
  lib/
    a.dll
    b.dll
    ...
  my_console_app.exe
  referenced.dll
  ...


After considerable research, I modified the application config file (App.config which Visual Studio copies to "my_console_app.exe.config") to include a <probing> element like this:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.8" />
    </startup>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <probing privatePath="lib" />
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
</configuration>


However this fails: the console app throws FileNotFoundException on startup with the message "Could not load file or assembly 'referenced.dll' or one of its dependencies."
What have I missed?

I dont quite understand why you did it that way, you can have the dll's in your directory of choice and then just add assembly reference using the visual studio UI and it will do so, the folders dont even have to be in the project...

Most of the dependencies are not managed assemblies and Visual Studio does not let me add references to them.
